# Working with dataframe variable names passed as arguments to the R function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I want to fit a statistical model (e.g. a linear one) for arbitrary variables from the dataframe passed as arguments to a function.

E.g.

```
myLm = function(x,y) {
    fit = lm(y~x, data=mtcars)}
myLm("cyl","mpg")
```

But this does not work.
How do I do that correctly?

Comment: What are "cyl" and "mpg" supposed to be? At the moment they are just strings.

Comment: you might want to try without the quotation marks, i.e. myLm(cyl, mpg)

Comment: You are passing string "cyl" not variable cyl.

Comment: "cyl" and "mpg" are variables from the dataframe mtcars. I understand that I'm passing strings - if I knew how to do it correctly, I wouldn't ask ;) this is for the purpose of explaining the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass a `formula` object to `lm` function. But you give `characters` in input of `myLM`.

You can change your function in this way

```
myLm = function(x,y) {
    fit = lm(formula(paste(x,"~",y)), data=mtcars)
}
myLm("cyl","mpg")
```

You still give `characters` input but they are converted inside your function `myLM`

Comment: Is there any general way to convert variable names (passed as strings) to the type "language"? that is, solve the problem without using the formula object.

Comment: What do a call a "language" type ?

Comment: E.g. I want to call a function within myLm that takes the variable names of the dataframe as an input but not via the formula expession

Comment: this expression has the type "language": typeof(quote(length(x)))
But I what I really want is mentioned above

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for but anyway hte function `lm` can be called only for a `formula` object.

Comment: OK, it's better to create a different question for another issue. Mark this problem solved

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you pass a formula object directly:

```
myLm <- function(f)
    lm(f, data=mtcars)

myLm(mpg ~ cyl)
```